# ASP.Net Checkbox inside a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm having a problem using a CheckBox inside a GridView in ASP.Net. I have a few rows with a CheckBox in each. There's a SAVE button for which when I click, it tries to get the CheckBoxes that are checked. The problem is that no matter what I do, the C# side won't recognize the checking action (although the view is updated fine). I tried to use Javascript and call a C# method from there - failed to pass the CheckBox ID through a hidden button. I tried various post back, html, asp and properties solutions but nothing seemed to help.

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="width: 958px; direction: ltr;"
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:checkbox ID="ShouldApprove" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

cs:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{                
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ShouldApprove");
        if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

There are a lot of posts about problems and solutions for those CheckBoxes, and I think I tried most of them and still, no success.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: If you populate the GridView in `Page_Load`, make sure that it is inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` conditional block. You will have to bind the data at the end of various event handlers however (`RowEditing`, `RowUpdating`, `RowCancelingEdit`, etc.).

Comment: @ConnorsFan As I wrote in my post, I tried toggling the PostBack booleans in various ways including yours.

Comment: You don't toggle the postback booleans.  you have to make sure you populate the gridview within `if( !Page.IsPostBack)` otherwise the gv will repopulate and you will lose all checkbox states.